# JQuery hiding elements bigger than variable in table

Tags: jquery, html-table

```
<input type="checkbox" id="canafford"></input>
```

I want it so when you check that checkbox, only upgrades that you can buy will appear. This is my upgrades code (it's a lot longer but I will show you only one part).

```
<tr id="up1">
  <td><button onclick="upgrade(2, 1)">Upgrade</button></td>
  <td>2 gold</td>
  <td>x2 Resting speed.</td>
</tr>
```

Each of them have id up1 up2 up3 etc. All I need is if gold (currency) is lower than its price it will hide.
Price is the second td in all of them; in this case its 2 gold.

Comment: what is Gold curreny and price ?? can you provide more code for proper suggestions

Comment: In example id up1 price is second <td> which is 2 gold.

Comment: make price a property rather than text, eg `<td data-price='2'>` then you can compare.   But otherwise, you're missing most of the question...

Comment: But how do i do that ? I know i need to add attribute to html, but **I need** some sort of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on few possible ways. This is one of working solutions.

Please check this snippet and feel free to edit variable 'goldAvailable'. Im actually looping through all tr elements on each click on this checkbox. If it is checked then im taking value from 2nd td item and parsing it to integer so i can compare it to available money. Everything that is higher then available will be hidden. On uncheck of box everything is getting to display:block

```js
var goldAvailable = 3;

$('#canafford').on('click', function(){ 
    if($('#canafford:checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
        $('tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
            var gold = $(this).html();
            gold= parseInt(gold.substring(0,gold.length-4));
            if(gold>goldAvailable) {
                $(this).closest('tr').css('display','none');
            }
        });
    } else {
            $('tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').css('display','block');
            });
    }
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="canafford"> </input>
    <table>
    <tr id="up1">
        <td><button onclick="upgrade(2, 1)">Upgrade</button></td>
        <td>2 gold</td>
        <td>x2 Resting speed.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="up1">
        <td><button onclick="upgrade(2, 1)">Upgrade</button></td>
        <td>3 gold</td>
        <td>x2 Resting speed.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="up1">
        <td><button onclick="upgrade(2, 1)">Upgrade</button></td>
        <td>4 gold</td>
        <td>x2 Resting speed.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="up1">
        <td><button onclick="upgrade(2, 1)">Upgrade</button></td>
        <td>5 gold</td>
        <td>x2 Resting speed.</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One problem. When i uncheck the checkbox, all of the columns get put into first column. Before: https://gyazo.com/1d900c2a866def81a9054a1ea1a297b6 after: https://gyazo.com/af28cae287cfe11229f4ac965070afd3

Comment: That is just because of $(this).closest('tr').css('display','block'); just change 'block' to whatever you need. Best regards @killereks

Comment: Thank you, i fixed it by adding ('display','table-row');

Answer (score -1):

```
<tr id="up1" data-price="2">
    <td><button onclick="upgrade(2, 1)">Upgrade</button></td>
    <td>2 gold</td>
    <td>x2 Resting speed.</td>
</tr>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#canafford').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('tr').each(function() {
                if ($(this).data('price') > myMoney) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('tr').show();
        }
    }
}
```